# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {"version":3,"file":"jquery-2.1.0.min.js","sources":["jquery-2.1.0.js"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

```
{"version":3,"file":"jquery-2.1.0.min.js","sources":["jquery-2.1.0.js"
```

this is the error i have encountered working in Asp.Net MVC 4.0 , while working with new script updated package of jquery to 2.1.0.js.

I updated my asp.net mvc 4.0 solution to latest jquery-ui using NuGet package console manager and facing this problem

Can anyone suggest any solution why this is happening ?

Comment: I have this same problem when using a `js.map` file created with VS Web Essentials. For some reason the .map file does not work well with the bundling. I got around it by deleting the `.map` file in the scripts directory and disabling the map files from being created in tools > options > web essentials > JS

Answer (score 1):

I encoutered with this error when I added the `.map` file as a script in

`<script src='/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.map'></script>`

But actually, the `.map` file is not javascript, so it cannot be given there.

It may be an issue in your case too.